# Ramanujan congruences for the partition function

Tags: combinatorics, modular-arithmetic, integer-partitions

Given the partition function $p(n)$, Ramanujan [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_congruences),

$$\begin{align}
p(5k+4) & \equiv 0 \pmod 5 \\
p(7k+5) & \equiv 0 \pmod 7 \\
p(11k+6) & \equiv 0 \pmod {11}
\end{align}$$

It was later proved in 2000 by Ken Ono that such congruences exist modulo every integer $m$ coprime to $6$. Some examples from the link above,

$$p(11^3 \cdot 13k + 237)\equiv 0 \pmod {13}$$

$$p(107^4\cdot 31k + 30064597)\equiv 0\pmod{31}$$

$$p(999959^4\cdot29k+ 28995221336976431135321047) \equiv 0 \pmod{29}$$

> **Q:** Assume a Ramanujan congruence
>   $$p(Ak+B) \equiv 0 \pmod m$$
>   with $A>11$. Must the factorization of $A$ involve an integer with a power $> 1$?

**P.S.** Is there a smaller example for $m=29$?